# Google-earth timestamp slider from months and years

Tags: timestamp, kml, google-earth

I want to use a timestamp to let users step through our monthly metadata, displaying different configurations of land stations at each month. My test examples look like this (eg):

```
<Placemark>
  <TimeStamp>
    <when>1901-01</when>
  </TimeStamp>
  <styleUrl>#emphasisedPlacemark</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>
      -0.18, 51.15,0
    </coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
<Placemark>
  <TimeStamp>
    <when>1901-02</when>
  </TimeStamp>
  <styleUrl>#emphasisedPlacemark</styleUrl>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>
      -0.52, 53.17,0
    </coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
```

This works, BUT the slider that GE introduces includes days! So you have to scroll through all the days in each month. That's going to create confusion because it's a monthly data set.

How can I get the time slider to just show years and months? I thought it would default to whatever the timestamp format was?

I don't see this being addressed in existing questions, esp. as the API is now deprecated.r

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to change the behavior of the slider, but if you have only a limited number of states you could add names to each placemark such as "Configuration in March" and use this for navigation instead. Clicking on the Name in the sidebar fast-forwards the time to the next month, as shown in the [ground overlay animation example](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/time#example2).

Comment: Thanks for that - though it's not practical for me, as I have 1380 months :)